# iterating each word in a line(string) c++

Tags: c++, string, file

So basically what I want to implement is that I have a text file and I have to find a specific word along with the location (location of line and where the word is on that line). how it could be implemented using basic knowledge of C++... I'm a newbie and haven't studies vector etc.Thanks for your help

```
fstream x;
x.open("file.txt);
while(getline(x,str)) {
    //extract word from str and save in str1
    if(reqWord == str1)
        print("match found");
}`
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Matching the word? Determine the line number? Determining the position in the line?. I would read the text line by line while keeping count of the number of lines read. Check each line using  `string::find()` and that also returns the location of the start of the string.

Comment: to find the word in the line along with the position in line ... well, line position can easily figure out ... but finding the position of the word in the line

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an advanced trick, but I suggest you try [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << str;

while(ss >> str1)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` in order to search a specific occurrence of a search term. It will return the position of the first occurrence, otherwise `npos` if it's not on the current line.
Please find below a working example:

**Edited - using regular expression with word boundary**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    std::cout << "Please input the file path" << std::endl;

    std::string path;

    std::cin >> path;

    std::ifstream file(path.c_str());

    if (file.is_open()) {
        std::string search;

        std::cout << "Please input the search term" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> search;

        std::regex rx("\\b" + search + "\\b");

        int line_no = 1;

        for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); ++line_no) {
            std::smatch m;

            if (std::regex_search(line, m, rx)) {
                std::cout << "match 1: " << m.str() << '\n';
                std::cout << "Word " << search << " found at line: " << line_no << " position: " << m.position() + 1
                          << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        std::cerr << "File could not be opened." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much :)

Comment: This will not find only words as OP requested, but any sub string match.

Comment: I've edited the answer to address the issue pointed by @zett42